# Creating a method that calls a promise OR completes an action quickly

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm creating an method that takes on the following form:

```
login() {
  var token = this.cookieManager.getCookie("token");

  if(!token)  
  {
     client.post(url, data).then(response => {
        this.accessToken = response.content;
     });
  } 
  else 
  {
    this.accessToken = token;
  }
}
```

The problem I can see right away is that the !token path could take awhile and so really my login method should return a promise.  The question is what to do about the else path?

I could create and return a promise but this promise wouldn't have any actual return value other then a hardcoded 'success'.  This seems odd so is there another option for handling this scenario?

Comment: You should make it a promise *for* the `accessToken` - that is what your `login` function basically acquires. No need to store that on a property when you can't know whether it's there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As @Esailija already mentioned if your function is asynchronous (returns promise in this case), it must always return promise. In ES7 [async](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:async_functions) keyword exists exactly for that purpose. But until ES7 you can garantee this behavior just wrapping your code with `Promise.resolve().then(() => {})` construction:

```
login() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    var token = this.cookieManager.getCookie("token");

    if (token) {
      return this.accessToken = token;
    }

    return client.post(url, data).then(response => {
      return this.accessToken = response.content;
    });
  });
}
```

Now `login` method also returns `accessToken` and I think it's clearer. Any errors that will be thrown inside of the callback passed to `then` will reject the promise.

Comment: Actually you code does not work because it is missing the `else`. You *don't* want to alway return `client.post(…)`.

Answer (score 1):

The else path can just return an already resolved promise.  So both paths return a promise.  In one case, it is already resolved, in the other case it will resolve when the async operation finishes.  In both cases, the caller just uses `.then()` on the promise the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the first promise, so your method appears synchronous to consumers. If your method is asynchronous you must return promise from all code paths, including throwing ones:

```
login() {
  try {
    var token = this.cookieManager.getCookie("token");

    if(!token)  
    {
      return client.post(url, data).then(response => {
        this.accessToken = response.content;
      });
    } 
    else 
    {
      this.accessToken = token;
    }
    return Promise.resolve();
  } catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}
```

Most promise libraries include a helper that makes this really easy:

```
login() {
  return Promise.try(_ => {
    var token = this.cookieManager.getCookie("token");

    if(!token)  
    {
      return client.post(url, data).then(response => {
        this.accessToken = response.content;
      });
    } 
    else 
    {
      this.accessToken = token;
    }
  })
}
```